# How to enable IntelliSense for Backbone in VS Code

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am trying to install TypeScript definitions for an example Backbone.js project.

In a project directory, I have issued the following commands:

```
npm init
npm install typings
typings install dt~backbone --global
```

This adds an `index.d.ts` and a `typings.json` file to a `\typings\globals\backbone` folder.

[image]

The console output is as follows:

[image]

As shown, the files are each 1 KB, and VS Code intellisense does not pick up any Backbone definitions. (The project folder does contain a jsconfig.json file.)

Should the "typings install dt~backbone..." command not install the actual backbone type definitions (found in `backbone-global.d.ts` (17 KB)), and also dependencies like underscore and jquery (each around 140 KB)? Does the `stripped reference` indicate some type of error?

How do I install these files/definitions (so that VS Code intellisense will work correctly)?

Comment: What version of typings are you using?

Comment: I just installed it now. Typings: 1.3.2. npm 2.14.4

Comment: If your project has a `jsconfig.json` file, then make sure that typings is contained in the project context defined by the location of the `jsconfig.json` file.

Comment: @JakubS: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give me an example please.

Comment: @RaelB Please look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38932121/6103920

Comment: I have created a `jsconfig.json` file as you describe, and it does not resolve the problem. I get the same result. Just tried on another computer installing latest node, and get the same result. Note: I have added to the question what the console shows.

Comment: @RaelB I've added an answer that describes required steps and explains why it didn't work from the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Foreword**

References are always stripped from Typings installation because of their ambiguous nature. The [Backbone definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/backbone/backbone.d.ts) file doesn't contain the definitions and just references backbone-global and underscore. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9677#issuecomment-226976620) about this.

**Installation and configuration**

By default, all JavaScript files opened in Visual Studio Code are treated as independent units. If you want to enable IntelliSense for the whole project remember to place the `jsconfig.json` file (can be empty) at the root of your project.

To install Typings manager execute `npm install typings --global`, and then install Backbone definitions with dependancies using following command:

`typings install dt~underscore dt~backbone dt~backbone-global --global`

You can also add the `--save` flag to create `typings.json` file. It's like dependencies part of `package.json` file but for Typings manager.

**Example**

I've just tested this quickly and **IntelliSense** seems to work as supposed after installing all referenced definitions and creating `jsconfig.json` file.

[image]

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "tmp"
    ]
}
```

**typings/index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="globals/backbone-global/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/backbone/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/underscore/index.d.ts" />
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.