# How to set intellisense for Angular.Js and Javascript in Visual Studio Code without adding TypeScript file reference on every js file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code and want to use it for the development of an AngularJs app. However, I am having the problem of adding a reference link on the top of all **JS** files.

like this.

```
 /// <reference path="path/to/typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all JavaScript files opened in Visual Studio Code are treated as independent units. If you want to enable IntelliSense for the whole project remember to place the `jsconfig.json` file at the root of your project.

Below is a `jsconfig.json` file which defines the JavaScript target to be ES6 and excludes the node_modules folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

You can get IntelliSense for AngularJS library through the use of type definition `.d.ts` files from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository. The typings are easily managed using [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) manager.

To install Typings manager execute `npm install typings --global`. This will install typings manager as your global npm module. Then you can install [AngularJS Definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs) using `typings install dt~angular --global` command. This will install and persist definitions from DefinitelyTyped repository as global definitions.

You can list available definitions using `typings search angular`.

Now you'll have IntelliSense available for all files in your project without the need of adding `///` reference.

You can find more in the [VS Code manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript).

Hope this helps!

Comment: `typings install dt~angularjs --global` is giving error that `typings ERR! message Unable to find "angularjs" ("dt") in the registry.`

Comment: @VikasBansal my mistake. It's *angular* not *angularjs*. You can search for definitions using "typings search"

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 x64

```
npm init

sudo npm install -g typings

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

typings install dt~angular --save --global

touch jsconfig.json
```

**UPDATE:**

Just wanted to advice against building new applications in AngularJS any more.

Angular2 + angular-cli is MUCH easier & expandable.

Believe me, Learn Angular 2 and save yourself MUCH hassle